# Find the minimum element of a stream, but bail out early if it's <= N

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find the minimum element of a large (hundreds of millions of elements) IntStream, but I can only use the result if it is > N, so I want to bail out as soon as I find an element <= N.  I expect the minimum to be <= N most of the time.

`IntStream.min()` doesn't short-circuit, so I'd be stuck processing all the elements.  The general `IntStream.reduce` doesn't short-circuit either.

`IntStream.noneMatch(x -> x <= N)` will ensure that the minimum element is > N and does short-circuit if it isn't, but doesn't actually tell me that minimum.  I'd have to maintain state in the predicate (and add synchronization or be limited to sequential streams) to remember the actual minimum.  Alternately, I could increment N and try again, possibly doing some sort of binary search over a likely range of N, but that sounds both slow and complicated.

How can I find the minimum of an IntStream, short-circuiting as soon as it's known to be <= N?

Comment: Unless you know ahead of time that all integers <=N are equal to each other, all you're actually finding is the first int <=N. You'd have to check the whole stream to find the absolute lowest.

Comment: @jpriebe Yes, all integers <= N are equal for my purposes.  The whole point is to avoid finding the absolute lowest once we know the minimum is <= N.

Comment: You'd need to use a short circuiting operator in Int stream, but the docs indicate that none of them take a lambda AND return an int or OptionalInt. This may make your problem unsolvable without a local variable, maybe AtomicInteger? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

Comment: from [stream javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) "A terminal operation is short-circuiting if, when presented with infinite input, it may terminate in finite time." - and none of xyzMatch operations (your case as well) guantees that the program stops with an arbitraty predicate

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, take a look at [protonpack lib](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack), specifically their `takeUntil(stream, predicate)` method seems to be relevant to your problem. @dominic-fox might have some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was to use `findAny` but then I reread the question. :-)

The difference, of course, is that `findAny` (or `findFirst`) short-circuits as soon as it finds a matching element. You want to short-circuit if a non-matching element is found, then reduce or accumulate the rest.

While accumulation is a form of mutation and is frowned upon by FP purists, it really comes in handy sometimes. Java 8 has some nice additions like `LongAccumulator` that do accumulation of primitive values in a low-contention way, making them suitable for parallel processing. You can put the accumulation step into the `peek` stream operation.

Unfortunately there is no "IntAccumulator" so you have to do processing using `long` values. You can either turn your source into a `LongStream` or map the `int` values into `long` values.

Once you've done that, it's probably most straightforward to handle short-circuiting using `allMatch`. Naturally, if `allMatch` returns false, short-circuiting has occurred and the accumulator doesn't actually have the minimum value. But it should have the minimum value examined so far, probably the one that triggered the short-circuiting.

Putting it together would look something like this:

```
IntStream istream = ... 
LongAccumulator acc = new LongAccumulator(Long::min, Long.MAX_VALUE);

if (istream.mapToLong(i -> i).peek(acc::accumulate).allMatch(i -> i > N)) {
    System.out.println("min was " + acc.get());
} else {
    System.out.println("a value was <= " + N);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cheat a little bit using anyMatch. Caution, this is untested and sorta sketchy. Note that, although it has a side effect, the inner lambda is clearly not stateful with regards to the stream.

```
final AtomicInteger min=new AtomicInteger(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
final int minLimit=?;
boolean isValid=!stream.anyMatch(i->{
    if(i<=minLimit){
        return true;
    }
    min.getAndAccumulate(i, Math::min);
    return false;
});
```

This works by exploiting anyMatch's short circuiting.

In actual fact, it may be impossible to do this without storing state outside the lambda. This is because in order to do this we must be both stateful, to store the minimum so far, short circuiting, and have user defined behavior. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) state that there are no such operators on IntStream.(Only limit is both stateful and short-circuiting). This seems like an issue about blocking/parallelism.

--Update--
Found an official [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) for the comment about parallelism:

"Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, such as findAny(), whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel should not change the result of the computation.

Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior, which are often lambda expressions. To preserve correct behavior, these behavioral parameters must be non-interfering, and in most cases must be stateless. Such parameters are always instances of a functional interface such as Function, and are often lambda expressions or method references."

Looks like the issue is the user supplied behavior, not the short circuiting.

Comment: Can't mutate a local from a lambda (captured locals must be final), for one, and you'd need synchronization if using parallel streams.  (As noted in my question: "I'd have to maintain state in the predicate (and add synchronization or be limited to sequential streams) to remember the actual minimum.")

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom fixed the captured local problem for now, gimmie a second to think on the other problem.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom explained why I think this is the best solution.

Comment: You may be right (though a parallel implementation can just poll between chunks of work to see if another chunk asked for early exit, no blocking required), but I'll wait to see if Brian Goetz, Stuart Marks or another Java architect says so definitively (and hopefully explains why).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I've added more information from official sources. Hope that's helpful!

Comment: another option is to have a clean stateless predicate and exploit .peek() to maintain state (current minimum). hacky...